# What was proved using Tarski's axioms?

Tags: geometry, axioms

Have Tarski's axioms been used in practice to demonstrate geometry results? For example, has the Pythagorean theorem been proven in this formalism?

I am interested in all the available proofs in this system.

Comment: See Alfred Tarski & Steven Givant, [Tarski's System of Geometry, BullSL (1999)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1182353619)

Comment: It rather looks like a historical and metamathematical paper than a math one, but thank you

Comment: Michael Beeson, [PROVING HILBERT’S AXIOMS IN TARSKI GEOMETRY](http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/TarskiProvesHilbert.pdf) and [A Constructive Version of Tarski's Geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4399)

Comment: Those articles are great, thank you!